# how to make the GPS function work normally when the app is running in the background

Tags: android

I'm doing a flutter project,my problem is:
how to make the GPS function work normally when the app is running in the background,i use Service,but only when the app is in the foreground can GPS get it.

this is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
//
        startService();
        Log.v(tag, "GPSService Started.");
    }
```

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void startService()
    {
        boolean isOpen = isOPen();
        if (isOpen) {
            initLocation();
            return;
        }
    }
```

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void initLocation() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.mainThis, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_CODE);
            return;
        }

        if (network&&gps){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500,0, listener); // network locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 8, listener); // gps
        }else if(network&&!gps){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500,8, listener); // n
        }else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 8, listener); // g
        }
    }

    LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateShow(location);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            
        }
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            updateShow(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateShow(null);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You should create a Foreground service to handle the position

Answer (score -1):

The article below has the caption "How to fetch user location in background with Flutter".
With subtopics like this,
How to fetch a user location
How to fetch it even if the app is running in the background
The limitations of the system

https://medium.com/@pierre.sabot/how-to-fetch-user-location-in-background-with-flutter-e3494021bdf5

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow. Please try to understand the relevant question and answer taking reference from the link and add the link as a source. Welcome to stackoverflow